# Sublime Text 2: Autocompleting html escaped characters (starting with ampersand)?

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I just started using Sublime Text and it's becoming my favorite editor by far.

A quick question though: Is it possible to configure/use a plugin to autocomplete special html characters, for example typing `&` and get a list of suggestions for `&amp;`, `&quot;` etc?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right site for this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sublime Text comes with a built-in special character encoder. Highlight the text you'd like to encode, hit `Ctrl+Shift+p`, and type `HTML: Encode Special Characters`.

If this isn't good enough and you'd like actual autocompletion, you can add to the HTML autocomplete list. Go to `"Browse Packages"` in the main menu then edit `HTML/HTML.sublime-completions` and add the autocompletions to the end of the list of autocompletions.